# Batch process Action Wizard insert javascript into PDF

Tags: javascript, action, batch-processing, acrobat, wizard

Can't find a way to do this. In Adobe Acrobat Pro XI how do I insert (embed) a javascript (document javascript) using the Adobe Acrobat "Action Wizard" (batch processing). I also need to later change out this old javascript with a altered new javascript every month or so on over 300 PDFs. This javascript runs automatically when the person (the reader) opens the PDF. I myself do not want to run a javascript, I only want to batch process (insert) a javascript into 300 PDFs. I need to do this by batch process because manually doing this would be too time consuming. If anyone knows, would you please write out a step by step on how to setup a "Action" to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Start by preparing the JavaScript you want each PDF to run and what event you want to trigger it. For example, and this is a simple one, if you want every PDF that's opened after running this action to say "Hello World", your script would be...

```
app.alert('Hello World');
```

1. Create a new Action
2. Select "More Tools"
3. Select "Execute JavaScript"
4. The script your action runs will need to inject the JavaScript that you want the PDF to run as a string. You'll need to give it a name ("init" in this case) so it appears in the "Document JavaScripts" list. So it will look like this...

   this.addScript("init", "app.alert('Hello World');")

Make sure the Action is set up to save the file.

Comment: Currently my javascript is in a notepad .txt format. I need to name this text file "init. js" or something like that? Then where or how do I tell Acrobat Action Wizard where to find this javascript file? So confused, thanks.

Comment: You don't need any .js files. You just copy your script and paste it into the Action Wizard step 4 above. This article is for an earlier version but the concepts are the same... https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/scripting-actions

Comment: At "Execute Javascript" > Specify Setting a large blank page opens named Javascript Editor, Create and edit Javascripts and in window says: "/* Put script title here */" .  /* init */ or just init? Then where does the rest javascript commands go that above supposingly is pointing to?

Comment: Cannot enter anything into "Document  Javascripts" No "Specify Settings" there.

Comment: A title isn't required. You just paste your script in there.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to joelgeraci in hopes to save others time.... should you have the need for a multiline message utilize the "\\n" vs. the \n.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31425543)